# Accessing MainWindow Properties from other classes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, subclass

I can modify/access controls and MessageBox with ease in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file of my WPF application.  However, when I create some folders and add classes there, I no longer have access to MessageBox nor do I have see the control names in the Intellisense dropdown.

(This seems quite elementary but I'm new to C# and WPF)

Answer (score 3):

You must be missing a namespace. You could do something like this:

---

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
 using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        internal static string message_ = string.Empty;
        MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupMessage();
        }

        private void SetupMessage()
        {
            message_ = "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

---

**OtherFile.cs :**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls; //are you missing this namespace?
namespace YourNameSpaceHere
{
        public class Messaging
        {
            Messaging()
            {
                MessageBox.Show(MainWindow.message_);
            }
        }
}
```

---

Note that I am using the same namespace in each file and by using the internal keyword the message can be accessed by anything as long as it is in the same namespace. I hope this helps!

Comment: I was having this problem as well and used Partial's answer. I was missing the following namespace: using System.Windows.Controls; Also, you need to use the `internal` keyword like in Partial's example.

Answer (score 1):

Does your classes have the right using  statement in that would allow you access to the class you are attempting to access within the new classes you've created?